# How save a list of users to database with foreach loop using java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to be able to send a list of users to my method, loop through each user and if user doesn't exist in database save it and if it exists throw an error.

I have this code so far:

```
public List<User> addUsers(@RequestBody List<User> userList) {
        List<User> newUserList = new ArrayList<>();
        userList.forEach(
                user -> {
                   userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail())
                           .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceAlreadyExistsException("User with ", "email already exists.", user.getEmail()));
                    newUserList.add(user);
                }
        );
        return userRepository.saveAll(newUserList);   
    }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-10-06T16:50:52.476+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Query { \"$java\" : Query: { \"email\" : \"domahaskins@gmail.com\"}, Fields: {}, Sort: {} } returned non unique result.",
    "path": "/user"
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Check do you have duplicate email id with `domahaskins@gmail.com` in db?

Comment: What are you actually confused about? The message tells you that the email you tried to save is already in the database in a column with a unique constraint.

Comment: @navnath I do, and for that user should throw an error and it should save other user

Comment: @MarsAtomic If one user exists in db then throe an error and if other don't save them. And is not throwing my custom error which means it did not enter foreach loop I guess

Comment: @user9347049 then return type of ` userRepository.findByEmail` should be `List<Em>` not `Optional`.. i guess

Comment: just reading the names of actions here should tip you off...some `userRepository` wants to `find` or Else `ResourceAlreadyExistsException`. Is this What you actually intend?

Comment: you are expecting only one record, but there are more than one in the database. 'returned non unique result' - can you enable unique constraint on email column?

Answer (score 0):

The logic used in the body of the loop is opposite on what you'd like to do.

```java
                user -> {
                  // this will throw for any user whose email is not present in the DB
                   userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail())
                           .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceAlreadyExistsException("User with ", "email already exists.", user.getEmail())); 

                    newUserList.add(user);
                }
```

[Optional#orElseThrow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-)

> Return the contained value, if present, otherwise throw an exception to be created by the provided supplier.

In result of the above, `newUserList` will contain only users whose email is already present in the DB.

EDIT:
Here's one solution for the task:

```java
                user -> {
                   userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail())
                           .ifPresent(u -> {throw new ResourceAlreadyExistsException("User with ", "email already exists.", u.getEmail());});

                    newUserList.add(user);
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you maybe provide working example?

Comment: @user9347049 Please see the updated answer for a sample solution

Comment: I have tried your code and in this line of code `.ifPresent(u -> {throw new ResourceAlreadyExistsException("User with ", "email already exists.", u.getEmail());});`  `u.getEmail()`is not recognized

Comment: @user9347049 you can replace `u.getEmail()` with `user.getEmail()`

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but it can be this way.

In your repo change return `Optional<Email>` to `Email` or whatever Object you have. Or you can have method like `boolean existsByEmail(String email)`

```
// Email findByEmail(String email) or boolean existsByEmail(String email)

public List<User> addUsers(@RequestBody List<User> userList) {
        List<User> newUserList = new ArrayList<>();
        userList.forEach(
            user ->{
                    // if(userRepository.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())){
                    if(userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail())!=null){
                        new ResourceAlreadyExistsException("User with ", "email already exists.", user.getEmail())
                    }
                    newUserList.add(user);
                }
        );
        return userRepository.saveAll(newUserList);   
}
```